# How to create a list by giving its values in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> list =[]
>>> list=input()
 32 323 32 42 323
```

When I'm doing this I have get the result only as a single string 
I need it to be like this how can I do that?

```
>>> list
['32','323','32','42','323']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split your input string by space:

```
>>> lst = input().split()
 32 323 32 42 323
>>> lst
['32','323','32','42','323']
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but from what it looks like, you want to append multiple items in one line to a list. In that case, you can use the `list.extend()` method:

```
list = []
list.extend(('32','323','32','42','323'))
```

Here is some [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) for further reading.